# How to track which line raised the exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

```
try
{
    //This code BlockLine no 1Line no 2Line no 3etc
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    LblError.Text= ex.Message + ex.InnerException.Message
}
```

I have a code with a `try catch` block. The `try` block has more than one line of  code. I would like to know which line present within the `try` block is raising the exception.

Comment: Can you share the Stack Trace of `ex`?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to look at the Stack Trace of the exception to track the line that throws the exception.

however if you want to get the full details about the exception use ToString method

Answer (score 0):

( using System.Diagnostics; )

```
    int lineNumber = (new StackTrace(ex, true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
    var fileName = (new StackTrace(ex, true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
```

Should give you where the problem started.